# How to padding for macOS google chrome?

Tags: css, scrollbar, padding

i would like to apply some padding in css for only Chrome on Mac, i've looked around but not found a solution.

I have tried webkits but dont seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried so far. Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to check the user agent string for "Macintosh" and "Chrome", and then use that information to add a class to the `<body>` or some other parent element.  Then just use that class to create a selector that adds the styles.

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates this basic idea by showing one message for Mac/Chrome users, and another for everyone else.

https://jsfiddle.net/aruyu6os/1/

Now, all that being said, what you're running into sounds like an issue with browsers rendering things differently.  Are you already using normalize.css?  If not, you'll find that normalizing styles is very important for making your website look consistent across different browsers.

Comment: thanks very much, exactly what i was looking for..